# Грязный и чёрный — однородные члены?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, однородные-неоднородные-определения

> *Вода, лившаяся тонким ручейком между камней, меняла цвет, принимая грязный, чёрный оттенок.*

***Грязный*** и ***чёрный*** — однородные члены?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, однородные. В данном контексте определения ***грязный*** и ***черный*** сближаются по производимому эффекту восприятия, выражают причинно-следственные и синонимические отношения.

[Однородные и неоднородные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98) (справочник Розенталя):

> Согласованные определения являются **однородными**:
> <...>
> **3)** если в условиях контекста, характеризуя предмет с разных сторон, объединяются каким-либо **общим признаком** (внешним видом, сходством производимого ими впечатления, отнесением к отдаленному общему понятию, причинно-следственной связью и т. д.):
> *Был **лунный, ясный** вечер* (Ч.) — ‘лунный, а потому ясный’;
> *Раздался **страшный, оглушительный** удар грома* (‘страшный, потому что оглушительный’);
> *Он прикрыл глаза **красными, воспалёнными** веками* (‘красными, потому что воспаленными’);
> *густой, чёрный дым;
>
> дальний, тёмный угол.*
>
> **4)** если в условиях контекста между определениями создаются **синонимические отношения**:
> *прозрачный, чистый воздух;
>
> красное, злое лицо;
>
> густое, тяжёлое масло.*

Сравните: *Одет он был в **грязный черный** ватник, в нескольких местах вымазанный побелкой...* [Виктор Пелевин. Омон Ра (1992)]
В этом предложении определения **неоднородны**, так как характеризуют предмет с разных сторон: степень чистоты и цвет.

P. S. Обратите внимание на "между камн**ей**". Использование родительного падежа считается разговорным (см.: [**МЕЖДУ, *предлог***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83)) и устаревающим (см: [**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=280626)).

> Сегодня нормативно: *между чем (между столами, между гаражами). Между чего* - устаревающий вариант.